# Capturing Outlook events

Tags: c++, outlook, mfc, outlook-addin

I'm trying to capture some outlook events using a MFC application. I started from this [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4230/Implementing-Outlook-2002-XP-Event-Sinks-in-MFC-C) sample.
I managed to capture email send and receive events but I couldn't capture *ObjectSync.Start/End* events. I believe I'm missing something.

Here is the ***QueryInterface*** method:

```
STDMETHODIMP CAppEventListener::QueryInterface(REFIID riid, 
                                           void ** ppvObj)
{
   if (riid == IID_IUnknown){*ppvObj = static_cast<IUnknown*>(this);}
   else 
       if (riid == IID_IDispatch){*ppvObj = static_cast<IDispatch*>(this);}
       else 
           if (riid == IID_ApplicationEvents){*ppvObj = static_cast<IDispatch*>(this);}
           else {*ppvObj = NULL;return E_NOINTERFACE;}
   static_cast<IUnknown*>(*ppvObj)->AddRef();
   return S_OK;
}
```

Here is the ***Invoke*** method

```
STDMETHODIMP CAppEventListener::Invoke(DISPID dispIdMember, 
                       REFIID riid, LCID lcid,
                       WORD wFlags, DISPPARAMS* pDispParams,
                       VARIANT* pVarResult, EXCEPINFO* pExcepInfo,
                       UINT* puArgErr)
{   
    //declaratin of l_date and l_time               
   switch(dispIdMember)
   {       
      case 0x0000fba7: HandleItemLoad(dispIdMember,l_date ,l_time);
               break;

      case 0x0000fab5: HandleOnReceive(riid,pDispParams,l_date ,l_time);
                   break;

      case 0x0000f002: HandleOnSend(riid,pDispParams,l_date ,l_time);
               break;

      case 0x0000fb40: HandleContextMenuDis(dispIdMember,l_date ,l_time);
               break;

      case 0x0000fba6: HandleContextMenuClo(dispIdMember,l_date ,l_time);
                   break;

      case 0x0000f006: HandleStartup(dispIdMember,l_date ,l_time);
               break;

      case 0x0000f007: HandleQuit(dispIdMember,l_date ,l_time);
               break;

      default:         HandleUnknown(dispIdMember,l_date ,l_time);
                   break;
   }
    return S_OK;
 }
```

And here is the ***AttachToSource*** method

```
STDMETHODIMP CAppEventListener::AttachToSource
                                 ( IUnknown* pEventSource )
{
     HRESULT hr = S_OK;

     IConnectionPointContainer* pCPC = NULL;
     hr = pEventSource->QueryInterface( IID_IConnectionPointContainer, 
                                  (void**)&pCPC );
     if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
     {
         hr = pCPC->FindConnectionPoint( IID_ApplicationEvents, 
                               &m_pConnectionPoint );
         if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
         {
             hr = m_pConnectionPoint->Advise( this, &m_dwConnection );
         }
         pCPC->Release();
     }  
     return hr;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

---

***UPDATE 1:***

Now I have a wrapper class for SyncObjectEvents

```
class CSyncObjectEventListener : public IDispatch
```

Here is my AttachToSource Method :

```
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE CSyncObjectEventListener::AttachToSource( IUnknown* pEventSource )
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

   IConnectionPointContainer* pCPC = NULL;
   hr = pEventSource->QueryInterface( IID_IConnectionPointContainer, 
      (void**)&pCPC );
   if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
   {
      HRESULT hr = pCPC->FindConnectionPoint(IID_SyncObjectEvents, &m_pConnectionPoint);              
      //Failure
      if (SUCCEEDED(hr) )
      {
         hr = m_pConnectionPoint->Advise( this, &m_dwConnection );
      }
      pCPC->Release();
   }

   return hr;
}
```

IID_SyncObjectEvents is defined this way:

```
const IID IID_SyncObjectEvents  =   {0x00063005,0x0000,0x0000,{0xc0,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x46}};
```

The `FindConnectionPoint` method fails to connect.

---

***UPDATE 2 :***

I have another class called ObjectSync : `class CObjectSync : public COleDispatchDriver`
And in CSyncObjectEventListener class I have this attribute `public : CObjectSync m_pObjectSync;`

And here is the code with which I'm trying to connect.

```
m_pSyncObjectEventListener = new CSyncObjectEventListener();
if(!m_pSyncObjectEventListener->m_pObjectSync.CreateDispatch( _T("Outlook.SyncObjects" ),&l_oleExcep))
{
    return 0;
}

m_pSyncObjectEventListener->AddRef();
m_pSyncObjectEventListener->AttachToSource( m_pSyncObjectEventListener->m_pObjectSync.m_lpDispatch);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code handles Application events only. You need to retrieve the SyncObject object and connect to its events (SyncObjectEvents), not _ApplicationEvents.

Comment: it's possible to connect to both events I guess? isn't it?

Comment: From the same wrapper class? What if the event dispids conflict? You really need to create a different wrapper class (CSyncObjectEventListener?) that uses IID_SyncObjectEvenst interface and dispids specific to that interface.

Comment: okay, thanks. I'll try making a new wrapper class and I'll come back to accept your answer once I get the notifications I want ;)

Comment: hi @dmitry, I have updated my question, would you kindly see my update

Comment: The GUID is wrong: DIID_SyncObjectEvents = {00063085-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}

Comment: How exactly are you retrieving the pEventSource argument?

Comment: hi @Dmitry : I managed to capture the events I want but I've made some major modifications. Now I'd like to know what are the additional informations I can retrieve from them (number of downloaded emails, number of emails downloaded with their body...) Is there a way to retrieve such informations? And one other question : what is the disp id number of OnError event?

Comment: It is 0xF003.  You can see it in OutlookSpy - click Namespace button, double click in the SyncObjects property, go to the IEnumVariant tab, double click on the "All Accounts" entry, go to the Events tab.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Dmitry. If I had enough reputation I would have given a bounty to you :)

Last but not least now how can I rereive the descripton of the error

HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE COutlookSyncEventSink::Invoke(     
    ...,
    DISPPARAMS *pDispParams,  
    ...)   
{             
    switch(dispIdMember)  
    {  
  
 case 61443:  
             //what to do to retreive the error
          
        break;  
 }  
   
    ...  
}

Comment: I mean when an eror accur while synchronization how to retrieve its description? (in the invoke method : `case 61443: //what to do to retreive the error` )

Comment: Your Invoke method receives the parameters. You just need to unpack them - keep in mind that they are in the reverse order. In case of the OnError event, the two parameters are Code (integer) and Description (string).

Comment: re hi @Dmitry and sorry if I'm disturbing you again ^^'
I noticed that the parameter **Description** of **OnProgress** methd is always empty, is that normal?

Comment: For me it is sometimes empty, sometimes not. What do you see in OutlookSpy?

Comment: Your are right, in OutlookSpy shows the progress : 
Progress (1, , 0, 1000)  
Progress (1, Sending Messages, 0, 1000)  
Progress (1, Downloading Messages, 0, 1000   

however within my code `CString l_desc((pDispParams->rgvarg)->bstrVal);` l_ desc is always empty

Comment: Show how you process the parameters.